# Vue component in Backpack button

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-backpack

I'm fairly new to both Laravel and Vue, I'm using backpack for my admin interface and i'm trying to add a button to the rows in one of my CRUD views. I've got teh button added and using a view with HTML and JS directly in teh view, but what I would like to do is use a Vue component for the button so I can re-use this elsewhere.
My view component works fine when I use it in a normal page, but when I add it to the button view it doesn't even register.

Password.Vue component file:

```
<template>

<div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bannerformmodal">Test</a>


    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="bannerformmodal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Reset Password</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="" method="">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="password" type="password">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component ready.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

resetPassword.blade.php in views/vendor/backpack/crud/buttons

```
<password></password>
```

button addition on crud controller:

```
$this->crud->addButtonFromView("line", "reset_Password","resetPassword" ,  "end");
```

Comment: Could you please also copy-paste your $this->crud->addButton() declaration and the blade file (including its name)? Cheers!

Comment: @crag_h no, no errors at all in the console

Comment: @tabacitu see edit, thanks

Comment: Hmm... to simplify debugging, can you please try loading a custom button without Vue.JS? Just a simple view with some custom text. See if that part is working ok?

Comment: @tabacitu yeah that does work fine, even adding the modal code into teh button directly works fine, but not when you use Vue. I am guessing there is maybe some issue with timing of Vue binding or something, but I'm not skilled enough in Vue or Backpack to work it out

Comment: Unfortunately, neither am I :-) Haven't used Vue.js enough to figure out the conflict, sorry... I'll try to direct some other people here, maybe they know. Cheers!

Comment: Are you using ajax datatable?  That wouldn't work.  You'd need to instantiate your `new Vue()` AFTER the table has the buttons loaded.  That also goes for whatever system you're using to create the modal (jquery maybe)